# "Experienced in" or "experienced of"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions, writing

What is the correct use of experienced, with *in* or *of*? For example,

> I have experienced **in** system development.
>
> I have experienced **of** system development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write

> I am experienced in system development.

Here *experienced* is used as an adjective.

Comment: Is "at" equally correct here, as in, "I am experienced at

Answer (score -2):

It sounds grammatically correct since it refers to a subject/activity.

Comment: What sounds grammatically correct? (There is no such word as *grammarly*.) The first alternative, the second, both?